# errors occur in WHERE query

Tags: sql, oracle

The main query works good. But WHERE query seems to be the problem. 
Following is the WHERE query.

```
#startDt# <!--[CDATA[<=]]--> TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND #endDt# <!--[CDATA[-->=]]> TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Then it gives me 'ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0' 
So I earased the TO_CHAR as below.

```
#startDt# <= (TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND #endDt# >= (TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Then it gives me ora-017'97 this operator must be followed by any or all'

The data type of DAY is String.

Can anyone fix this problem?

Oh here is my full query.

```
<select id="ContentStatis.statis" parameterClass="map" resultMap="ContentStatis">
SELECT X.*
  FROM
      ( 
        SELECT 
                    (CASE
                             WHEN DAY.DAY = '단위 합계' THEN DAY.DAY
                             ELSE TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (DAY.DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') 
                       END
                    ) AS DAY,
                    DAY.WEEK,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT AS MNOT_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_500K AS MOVIE_500K_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE_1M AS MOVIE_1M_CNT,
                    RSC.MOVIE AS MOVIE_CNT,
                    RSC.EXAM AS EXAM_CNT,
                    RSC.WEB AS WEB_CNT,
                    RSC.IMG AS IMG_CNT,
                    RSC.INTERRAC AS INTERRACTIVE_CNT,
                    RSC.DOC AS DOC_CNT,
                    MNOT.SUM_STD_CNT + RSC.MOVIE_500K + RSC.MOVIE_1M + RSC.MOVIE + RSC.EXAM + RSC.WEB + RSC.IMG + RSC.INTERRAC + RSC.DOC TOT_CNT
          FROM 
                    /* 날짜 */
                   (SELECT 
                                TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130501','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD') AS DAY
                               ,CEIL(
                                      (
                                        to_number(substrb(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130501','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'), -2, 2)) 
                                      + 7 
                                      - to_number(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('20130501','YYYY-MM-DD')+LEVEL- 1, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD'),'D'))
                                      )/7 
                                     )|| ' 주차'  WEEK
                      FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + LEVEL - 1  <![CDATA[<=]]>  TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT '단위 합계', '' FROM DUAL
                    ) DAY LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   /* 리소스 */
                    (
                     SELECT 
                                 NVL(DT_G.COMM_DT, '단위 합계') COMM_DT
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_500K), 0) AS MOVIE_500K
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE_1M), 0) AS MOVIE_1M
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.MOVIE), 0) AS MOVIE
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.EXAM), 0) AS EXAM
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.DOC), 0) AS DOC 
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.IMG), 0) AS IMG
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.WEB), 0) AS WEB
                                ,NVL(SUM(DT_G.INTERRAC), 0) AS INTERRAC
                       FROM 
                                (
                                 SELECT
                                              COMM_DT
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K END MOVIE_500K
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE_1M
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP10' THEN SUMT.SUM_500K+SUMT.SUM_1M END AS MOVIE
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP11' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS EXAM
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP12' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS DOC
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP13' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS IMG
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP14' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS WEB
                                            , CASE SUMT.RSC_TP_DSCD WHEN 'RTP01' THEN SUMT.SUM_STD_CNT END AS INTERRAC
                                  FROM (
                                              SELECT RSC_TP_DSCD, SUM(STDY_CNT) AS SUM_STD_CNT, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M) AS SUM_1M, SUM(MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K) AS SUM_500K, COMM_DT
                                              FROM (
                                                        SELECT RSC_SNO, STDY_CNT, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N1M, MOVIE_STDY_CNT_N500K, COMM_DT
                                                          FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                                                        WHERE PKG_SNO = 0  AND RSC_SNO != 0
                                                        AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
                                                        ) CNT
                                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN LRMS.V_LRRM_RSC RSC ON CNT.RSC_SNO = RSC.RSC_SNO
                                              GROUP BY RSC_TP_DSCD, COMM_DT
                                            ) SUMT
                                ) DT_G
                         GROUP BY ROLLUP(DT_G.COMM_DT)
                    ) RSC ON DAY.DAY = RSC.COMM_DT
                    /* M노트 */
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT NVL(SUM(STDY_CNT), 0) AS SUM_STD_CNT, NVL(COMM_DT, '단위 합계') COMM_DT
                        FROM LRMS.V_EBSM_PKG_RSC_COMM_CNT
                      WHERE PKG_SNO != 0  AND RSC_SNO = 0
                                AND COMM_DT BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20130530', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD')
                      GROUP BY ROLLUP(COMM_DT)
                    ) MNOT  ON DAY.DAY = MNOT.COMM_DT
        ) X

 WHERE 1=1
 and X.TOT_CNT IS NOT NULL 

<isNotEmpty property="startDt" prepend="AND">
    <isNotEmpty property="endDt">
        (#startDt# <![CDATA[<=]]> TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD') AND #endDt# <![CDATA[>=]]> TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYYMMDD'))

    </isNotEmpty>
</isNotEmpty>
</select>
```

And the errors are

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];

--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.

--- Check the ContentStatis.statis-InlineParameterMap.

--- Check the statement (query failed). 
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLDataException: 'ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and 
+9999, and not be 0' ; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException: 
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.

--- Check the ContentStatis.statis-InlineParameterMap.

--- Check the statement (query failed).

--- Cause: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01841: 'ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0'

AND I USE ORACLE

Comment: "So I earased the TO_CHAR as below" --- was it a spontaneous action or did you follow some general (meaningful) idea?

Comment: Give us your full query.  Properly format your query for readability.  Give us the type of SQL databse you are using (MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, etc.), what language are you using to perform the query (PHP, command line, Java, ASP.NET, etc.)  Give us the **exact** error message, properly formatted using the tags given to you by StackOverflow.

Comment: I just posted the full query. Hope it helps

Comment: Second one is syntactically incorrect: the to_char is removed, but the format string for the to_char was left behind (YYYYMMDD). First example expects a string input in the format YYYY-MM-DD, converts it to a date, then converts it to a string in a different format (YYYYMMDD) and uses the string to compare to the column. So is the input string truly a string in the YYYY-MM-DD format? Full 4-digit year? Is the column truly a string (not date) in YYYYMMDD format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using dates in the format being specified. For example:

```
TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

should be

```
TO_DATE('2013-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or

```
TO_DATE('20130501', 'YYYYMMDD')
```